# Python stompest and yield

Tags: python, python-2.7, yield

I'm having problems with using the Python Stompest library to yield frames as they arrive. When I include the `yield` keyword in the function, the code does not block and wait for a frame like it should.

```
def receive(stomp):
    received_messages = 0
    while True:
        frame = stomp.receiveFrame()
        stomp.ack(frame)
        yield frame.body
```

However, if all I do is print the frame body, then it waits like it should

```
def receive(stomp):
    while True:
        frame = stomp.receiveFrame()
        stomp.ack(frame)
        print frame.body
```

Is there something wrong with using `yield` in this context?

Comment: How are you calling `receive`? If you're just doing `x = receive(whatever)` and that's it, then no blocking will occur because generator functions do nothing unless you iterate over them or call `next` on them repeatedly. Try `for frame in receive(whatever): do_something_here()`

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put `yield` in a function, it becomes a function that returns a generator, which is only evaluated lazily when it is required in an iteration or comprehension of some sort. In the first case you gave,

```
>> x = receive(stomp)
>> type(x)
<type 'generator'>
```

To make the generator `x` actually do something, you can do this:

```
for frame in x: print(frame)
```

When you iterate over the generator, it will actually execute the statements in the function you defined (including blocking until a frame arrives) and return the frame for each iteration. Creating a generator object with `yield` saves you the trouble of implementing the state to remember which iteration you are on manually.

Comment: That was the answer. I was calling it like `x = receive(stomp)` instead of iterating over it.